# SharePoint2010 FBA accessing wcf list data service

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fba

```
context = new TestingDataContext(new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
```

We are getting the context for classic mode authentication `SharePoint` site, but for `FBA`(claims based authentication) configured we are not able to access the list and getting time out error.

Tried to pass the  default credentials:

```
context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

It is throwing time out error while accessing list.

Answer (score 1):

According to the web at large, REST services are not anonymous-access-capable.  There is some discussion that you might be able to get around it using the Secure Store Service, but I do not have the specifics about that.